# Заменить строку в jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть ссылка вида:

```
<a class="none" rel="tooltip" title="Минус" href="javascript:setRateComment({{ @post.id }}, 'comment-id-tmp', 'minus')">
```

Требуется заменить `comment-id-tmp` на другое значение.
Как реализовать?

Comment: по другому обрабатывайте такие кнопки, тогда будет доступно "this" в функции setRateComment

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
$("a").attr("href","javascript:setRateComment({{ @post.id }}, 'comment-id-main', 'minus')");
```

[вот](http://jsfiddle.net/BAwa4/1/)